# SQL Server 2012 - using select * into along with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

### Hi I have the the following code:

```
use TSQL2012; 
go

if OBJECT_ID('Sales.FreightTotals') is not null drop table 
Sales.FreightTotals
go 

declare @shipperid as nvarchar(max) ='';
declare @dsql as nvarchar(max);
select @shipperid += quotename(shipperid,'')+',' from sales.Orders group by 
shipperid;
set @shipperid = LEFT(@shipperid, LEN(@shipperid)-1)

print @shipperid; 

set @dsql='
select empid,'+@shipperid+' from
(select empid, shipperid, freight from Sales.Orders )as d  
pivot(sum(freight) for shipperid in('+@shipperid+')) as pvt
order by pvt.empid  
'
```

print @dsql

--exec sp_executesql @dsql

```
select * into Sales.FreightTotals from @dsql;
```

---

I am trying to use select * into with dynamic pivot as shown above.If I use

```
exec sp_executesql @dsql
```

I get the following result the result i am looking for

```
empid       1                     2                     3
----------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------
1           2194.73               3259.99               3381.92
2           2281.09               4350.20               2065.12
3           2491.74               4258.90               4134.10
4           3129.39               4926.73               3290.02
5           1218.27               1991.84               708.60
6           1049.83               1270.42               1460.22
7           1204.60               3155.18               2305.66
8           1889.27               3297.40               2301.21
9           726.41                1734.19               865.66

(9 rows affected)
```

---

but if I do 
    select * into Sales.FreightTotals from @dsql;

i get:

```
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Must declare the table variable "@dsql".
```

any suggestion as to why this is the case?

Comment: Try this one  `exec  'select * into Sales.FreightTotals from ('+ @dsql+') as tmp;`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your local variable '@dsql' is declared within your stored procedure.

So when you call the sp the variable is declared before it's printed - 'PRINT'

When you run the same printed line, the varable has not been declared and so you recieve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
set @dsql='
select empid,'+@shipperid+'
into Sales.FreightTotals -- into is here
from
(select empid, shipperid, freight from Sales.Orders )as d  
pivot(sum(freight) for shipperid in('+@shipperid+')) as pvt
order by pvt.empid  
'

print @dsql -- print for check

exec sp_executesql @dsql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a string instead of a table in the from clause.

If you really need dynamic SQL you can use the insert ... exec workaround.

Insert into Sales.FreightTotals
Exec sp_executesql @dsql;

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
exec ('select * into Sales.FreightTotals from ('+@dsql+')t;')
```

Thanks.